# Redirect wordpress uploads folder to s3 bucket using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-s3

I'm trying to redirect my uploads folder to my s3 bucket using htaccess in wordpress however it's not working. All the images on my site are still getting served locally from the server instead of linking to the bucket.

This is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [L]

# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
```

Comment: I would suggest using [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) which has this functionality built in. And [here's a tutorial](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-with-wordpress).

Comment: I am using it. it replaces it on the single posts but not on my theme homepage thumbnails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. You need to put the rule **ABOVE** your wordpress rule because wordpress rules route **every** request to index.php.
Next you will need to use `mod_proxy` with the use of the `[P] flag` because regardless of not specifying redirect in the rewriterule, Apache will do it anyway because the substitution URL is a new domain. So Apache will perform a Redirect. So using `[P] flag` should proxy the content instead of doing a redirect. This should accomplish what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [P]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: `mod_proxy` would cause the local server to fetch the image from the bucket before returning it to the client, burdening the server, wouldn't it? That would defeat the whole purpose of hosting files on S3.

Comment: `That would defeat the whole purpose of hosting files on S3` @FabienSnauwaert Actually you don't know what his purpose is for using it. Hosting on s3 is for many reasons. Security, unlimited disk space, redundancy etc. The question was asking for assistance with code not how he should use s3 with wordpress. Your comment should be directed at his question. I only fixed why it wasn't working.

Comment: Changing the rewrite rule's flag from [P] to [R,L] does force the browser to load the asset from S3 and not proxy it.