# Use custom url with S3 uploads plugin for wordpress to AWS cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have taken over a WordPress blog that uses the [S3 uploads plugin](https://github.com/humanmade/S3-Uploads) to host images via AWS Cloudfront on an S3 instance.

The cloudfront url is something like: `https://ake12sa38qwe.cloudfront.net`, so the image source linked on my blog looks like: `https://ake12sa38qwe.cloudfront.net/uploads/image.jpg`. To improve my backlink profile, I want to use a custom URL with my domain instead of the cryptic cloudfront url, something like: `www.mydomain.com/uploads/image.jpg`

I have already managed to set up an alternative URL (*.mydomain.com) in [Amazon Cloudfront Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) and a redirect via CNAME record with my web hosting service (Hostinger). However, I don't know how to implement the alternative URL into the S3 plugin configuration and what else I need to do to get my custom url set in the media upload manager on wordpress.

My S3 plugin configuration in `wp-config` looks like this:

```
define('S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET', 'mydomain-wordpress-media');
define('S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_URL', 'ake12sa38qwe.cloudfront.net');
define('S3_UPLOADS_HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL', 24 * 60 * 60);
define('S3_UPLOADS_KEY', 'AASKL9LKJLKJ3B3KK');
define('S3_UPLOADS_SECRET', 'asdnkljasdhLKJSADLKJasdlkhj21');
define('S3_UPLOADS_REGION', 'eu-central-1');
define('S3_UPLOADS_AUTOENABLE', false);
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me further...

Comment: Have you set up CloudFront origin to be the S3 bucket?

Comment: Yes, I did... So is it legit to `define('S3_UPLOADS_BUCKET_URL', 'www.mydomain.com');`?

Comment: Another way is to redirect image links via htaccess as defined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165332/8900664